# Emacs: copying text (without killing it)

Tags: emacs

In Emacs, how do I copy a region of text (to paste it in another buffer) without killing it (for example: the file I want to copy from is opened in read-only mode, so killing it isn't an option).

Comment: Isn't this a question for Super User? (http://superuser.com/)

Comment: Probably, but check out the plethora of emacs tags http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/emacs in SO vs SU
http://superuser.com/questions/tagged/emacs

Comment: Emacs questions are tricky, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36017/what-site-should-host-questions-about-emacs-keybinding for some discussion in a slightly different context.

Answer (score 52):

Just mark it (<kbd>C-space</kbd> at one end of the range, and move to the other end) and use <kbd>M-w</kbd> (`kill-ring-save`):

> (kill-ring-save BEG END)
>
> Save the region as if killed, but don't kill it.

Answer (score 8):

Two additional ways:

- You can also select it with the mouse (mouse-button-1), which will copy the region to the kill ring.
- When the buffer is read-only, you can use the `kill-*` routines (<kbd>C-w</kbd> and <kbd>C-k</kbd>) to copy the region/line to the kill ring.  Emacs will beep at you, but it's a documented feature:

> If the buffer is read-only, Emacs will
>   beep and refrain from deleting the
>   text, but put the text in the kill
>   ring anyway.  This means that you can
>   use the killing commands to copy text
>   from a read-only buffer.

Comment: The select to clipboard behavior works in X11, but I believe that's because it is a X11 behavior. Or does it work in other contexts as well?

Comment: @dmckee The interaction with X is independent of the kill-ring.  You can copy to X w/out the kill-ring, and you can put things on the kill-ring w/out X.  But, generally they are hooked together.  I was only describing the Emacs behavior, which works regardless of whether you're in X or not.

Answer (score 2):

I use the command

```
M-x append-to-file
```

the problem with this is that if the file you want to copy it to is open, you will need to refresh the screen somehow so that the new stuff appears there. Also, the stuff you copied will go to the end of the file you choose as the target.

You might also find the commands

```
M-x write-region
```

and

```
C-x i   (insert-file)
```

useful.